# Is $\{(1,0,\dots,0)\}$ a deformation retract of $\{x \in S^n: x_n \ge -\epsilon\}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $1 >\epsilon > 0$ and consider the set
$$V:= \{x \in S^n: x_{n+1} \ge -\epsilon\}.$$
Let $p:=(1,0,\dots,0)$. Is $\{p\}$ a deformation retract of $V$?

I tried to consider
$$F: V \times [0,1]\to V: (x,t) \mapsto \frac{tx + (1-t)p}{\|tx+(1-t)p\|}$$
but this is not well-defined, as the denominator can become $0$.

Comment: Your title does not match your post.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you. Edited. To get a second opinion, do you think that the statement is true?

Comment: A deformation retract of $\{p\}$ cannot contain more than one point. You meant to ask whether $\{p\}$ was a deformation retract of $V$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks. Edited. Do you think the statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the terminology is the other way around: one says $p$ is a deformation retract of $V$.

For $\epsilon\ge1$ this is asking whether $p$ is a deformation retract of $S^n$. For $\epsilon<1$, consider the point $q=(0,\dots,0,1)$ instead. (you can then translate $q$ to $p$ continuously, since $p\in V$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but should an explicit deformation retract look like then?

Comment: I'll let you work that out yourself for now. What you already did is on the right track. When does the denominator become $0$?

Comment: I think the denominator won't become $0$ anymore when you take the point you propose. So I guess it is ok for that point, but I'm not seeing why you can replace the point.

Comment: What is your definition of a deformation retract?

Comment: A subspace $A$ of $X$ is called deformation retract if there is a continuous map $r: X \to A$ such that $r$ is the identity on $A$ and such that there is a homotopy $F: X \times [0,1]\to X$ such that $F(A,t) \subseteq A$ for all $t$ and the homotopy connects the identity and the retraction.

Comment: So in this case, we see that the northpole $\{q\}$ which you propose is a deformation retract of $V$ via the homotopy I wrote down in the OP.

Comment: I simply don't see how we can assume that the point is $q$. Can you elaborate why we can "translate $q$ to $p$ continuously"?

Comment: Right. I think an explicit formula for such a map would be quite ugly, but the picture goes like this. V is homeomorphic to a ball of dimension $n$. What I am saying is that given two points $p, q$ in the interior of the ball, there exists a homeomorphism that sends $q$ to $p$ and that fixes the boundary of the ball. Composing this with the homotopy should give you what you want.

Comment: These are a lot of non-trivial claims: I would need that a homeomorphism between the ball and $V$ sends $p,q$ to the interior of the ball and then I need to show that such a homeomorphism exists.

Comment: To get this homeomorphism, use the homotopy you already constructed to get a homeomorphism to a subset of the hemisphere containing $q$. Then project onto the plane orthogonal to $q$. This gives a homeomorphism to a ball, and the only point on the boundary are those that were on the boundary to being with.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try to fill in the details.

Comment: I recommend doing the 2 dimensional case first, to build intuition. Higher dimensions are very similar. And draw a lot of pictures. Good luck!